# Remove "like items" objects in array based off timestamp

Tags: javascript

I have an array of (could be more than this), that has a `uid` and a `timestamp`.

My goal is to cycle through an object and if their `uid` is equal to each other, only keep the object with the greater timestamp.

```
[
  {
    "uid":"u55555",
    "timestamp":1536273731,
    "id":"8a655addf1293b6d780ff6469c0848dd",
    "name":"John Doe",
  },
  {
    "uid":"u55555",
    "timestamp":1536273831,
    "id":"8v8799817981mcmccm89c81282128cm2",
    "name":"John Doe",
  },
  {
    "uid":"u1111",
    "timestamp":1536253940,
    "id":"c8898202n2nu929n2828998228989h2h2",
    "name":"Test Testerson",
  },
  {
    "uid":"u55555",
    "timestamp":1536274940,
    "id":"fb990b1734e4aaea2e39315952e13123",
    "name":"John Doe",
  },
  {
    "uid":"u11111",
    "timestamp":1538275741,
    "id":"99s9hshs88s8g89898899898897a79s",
    "name":"Test Testerson",
  },
]
```

Does anyone know how I would do this?

I've been playing around with the following but can't get it just right.

```
var result = signatures.filter(function (a) {

   //logic here

}, Object.create(null));
```

Comment: is the data sorted?

Comment: @NinaScholz while it may look sorted in my example, I can't count on it being sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort the original array by timestamp and then reduce it to only a set of unique `uid`s using `sort` and `reduce`.

```js
var data = [{"uid": "u55555","timestamp": 1536273731,"id": "8a655addf1293b6d780ff6469c0848dd","name": "John Doe",}, { "uid": "u55555", "timestamp": 1536273831, "id": "8v8799817981mcmccm89c81282128cm2", "name": "John Doe", }, { "uid": "u1111", "timestamp": 1536253940, "id": "c8898202n2nu929n2828998228989h2h2", "name": "Test Testerson", }, { "uid": "u55555", "timestamp": 1536274940, "id": "fb990b1734e4aaea2e39315952e13123", "name": "John Doe", }, { "uid": "u11111", "timestamp": 1538275741, "id": "99s9hshs88s8g89898899898897a79s", "name": "Test Testerson", }];

var result = data
  .sort((a,b) => b.timestamp - a.timestamp) //Sort by timestamp descending
  .reduce((a,i) => a.some(n=>n.uid === i.uid) ? a : [...a, i], []); //If item is already accounted for, ignore it

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems very simple and concise. Thank you for the comments, very easy to understand what is going on.

Comment: Glad I could help! That said, I generally get a bit nervous that I may be doing something dumb whenever my answer doesn't match Mark's or Nina's... I'm iterating through the array twice (once to sort, once to reduce) whereas I don't believe that's the case with theirs. I'd imagine mine could be less efficient, albeit less lines.

Comment: Ah, very true. Well, I am thankful for @NinaScholz and Mark's example in case it becomes a bit more of a efficiency problem

Comment: ...and you avoid making an unused object, which I think is nice.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an object keyed to the `guid` and loop through your array adding the item to the object if it either isn't already there or the time is smaller. Then just take the values from that object:

```js
let arr = [{"uid":"u55555","timestamp":1536273731,"id":"8a655addf1293b6d780ff6469c0848dd","name":"John Doe",},{"uid":"u55555","timestamp":1536273831,"id":"8v8799817981mcmccm89c81282128cm2","name":"John Doe",},{"uid":"u1111","timestamp":1536253940,"id":"c8898202n2nu929n2828998228989h2h2","name":"Test Testerson",},{"uid":"u55555","timestamp":1536274940,"id":"fb990b1734e4aaea2e39315952e13123","name":"John Doe",},{"uid":"u11111","timestamp":1538275741,"id":"99s9hshs88s8g89898899898897a79s","name":"Test Testerson",},]

let newArr = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    if (!obj[item.uid] || obj[item.uid].timestamp < item.timestamp)
      obj[item.uid] = item
    return obj
  }, {}))
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could find the object and check the timestamp or add the actual object to the result set.

```js
var array = [{ uid: "u55555", timestamp: 1536273731, id: "8a655addf1293b6d780ff6469c0848dd", name: "John Doe" }, { uid: "u55555", timestamp: 1536273831, id: "8v8799817981mcmccm89c81282128cm2", name: "John Doe" }, { uid: "u1111", timestamp: 1536253940, id: "c8898202n2nu929n2828998228989h2h2", name: "Test Testerson" }, { uid: "u55555", timestamp: 1536274940, id: "fb990b1734e4aaea2e39315952e13123", name: "John Doe" }, { uid: "u11111", timestamp: 1538275741, id: "99s9hshs88s8g89898899898897a79s", name: "Test Testerson" }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var index = r.findIndex(({ uid }) => uid === o.uid);
        if (index === -1) {
            return r.concat(o);
        }
        if (o.timestamp > r[index].timestamp) {
            r[index] = o;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new Object, which uses keys based on the UID; then populates it with only the last entries. Perhaps not the smallest code possible, but it's a method.

```js
let sorted = {};
let original = [{
    "uid": "u55555",
    "timestamp": 1536273731,
    "id": "8a655addf1293b6d780ff6469c0848dd",
    "name": "John Doe",
  },
  {
    "uid": "u55555",
    "timestamp": 1536273831,
    "id": "8v8799817981mcmccm89c81282128cm2",
    "name": "John Doe",
  },
  {
    "uid": "u11111",
    "timestamp": 1536253940,
    "id": "c8898202n2nu929n2828998228989h2h2",
    "name": "Test Testerson",
  },
  {
    "uid": "u55555",
    "timestamp": 1536274940,
    "id": "fb990b1734e4aaea2e39315952e13123",
    "name": "John Doe",
  },
  {
    "uid": "u11111",
    "timestamp": 1538275741,
    "id": "99s9hshs88s8g89898899898897a79s",
    "name": "Test Testerson",
  },
];


original.forEach((item) => {
  if (sorted[item.uid] == undefined || sorted[item.uid].timestamp < item.timestamp) {
    // if key doesn't exist, create it
    // if key exists but timestamp is newer, replace it
    sorted[item.uid] = {
      uid: item.uid,
      timestamp: item.timestamp,
      id: item.id,
      name: item.name
    }
  }
});

console.log(sorted);
```